# Functional type with let - unresolved reference: invoke

Tags: kotlin

I have `onClick` functional type declared as class field `val onClick: (() -> Unit)? = null`

And want to use it like this:

```
if (onClick != null) {
    item.setOnClickListener { onClick.invoke() }
}
```

This code works, but when I replaced it with `let` function, it shows error `unresolved reference: invoke`:

```
onClick?.let {
    item.setOnClickListener { it.invoke() }
}
```

Why it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `it` here is the receiver of the second lambda (being passed into `setOnClickListener`), not the first lambda (`let`).  Declare the parameter to the first lambda by giving it a name explicitly, then use that, e.g.

```
onClick?.let { handler ->
    item.setOnClickListener { handler.invoke() }
}
```